# Scheme Map Function

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am trying to find the length of a list using Map/Foldl/Foldr

```
(define (suml lst)
(length lst))
Input : (suml '(1 2 3))
Output : 3
Input : (suml '(((((2)))) (1)))
Output: 2
```

How can I modify it work with foldl/map/foldr?

Comment: You cannot find the length of a list using `map` because `map` applies a function to *each element* of a list, but knowing the length requires having information about the *whole* list. Your code is a bit silly though, since `length` is already a function that gets the length of a list. Just drop the `map` and use `(length lst)` (and at that point, you can drop the `suml` wrapper, since it’s just `length`). Or are you actually trying to do something else?

Comment: How should the function work. Can you give example input and expected result?

Comment: I updated the OP , please check :) Sylwester Alexis King

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, map takes a function and applies it elementwise.  A function that uses map will create a list of the same length.  To create a length function, we are condensing a list to a single value.  This is the purpose of fold.

`(define (length l)
  (foldr (lambda (_ cur-length) (+ 1 cur-length)) 0 l))`

When you think about foldr, you should think about it just replacing cons in a list with the function and the empty list with the base case argument.  Take the following example:

`'(1 2 3 4)
= (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 '()))))
(foldr f base '(1 2 3 4))
= (f 1 (f 2 (f 3 (f 4 base))))`

It turns out, foldl also works in this case because we're just adding one for every element, it doesn't matter if we go left to right or right to left.

`(define (length l)
  (foldl (lambda (_ cur-length) (+ 1 cur-length)) 0 l))`